# SQLServerException: "[...] The index 1 is out of range [...]" when using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring, jdbc

I'm having a problem with a couple of sql-statements when i'm using *NamedParameterJdbcTemplate* (*mssql-jdbc 7.2.0*).

Example:

```
return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT Mitarbeiter, CASE "+
        " WHEN Storno = 1 THEN Dauer * -1 "+
        " WHEN Storno = 0 THEN Dauer " +
        " END AS Wert "+
        "FROM Werte " +
        "WHERE Mitarbeiter IN (:mitarbeiter)", parameterSource, rs -> {
    HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        hashMap.put(rs.getString("Mitarbeiter"), rs.getInt("Wert"));
    }
    return hashMap;
});
```

When i am executing the sql-statement in the SQL Server Management Studio it works fine. But when i am executing the statement with the jdbcTemplate the *SQLServerException "[...] The index 1 is out of range [...]"* is raised.

Maybe some reserved char is causing the problem?

**Update:**

After downgrading spring-jdbc from 7.2.0 to 7.0.0 my code works fine. It seems that the new version has some issues with parsing the sql-statement. Take a look at https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/952. The issue will be fixed with version 7.2.1.

Comment: You can replace `Dauer * -1` with `-Dauer`

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  I don't see how you are concluding that the `- 1` in the query is the cause of your problem.

This query is fine:

```
SELECT Mitarbeiter,
       (CASE WHEN Storno = 1 THEN Dauer * -1 
             WHEN Storno = 0 THEN Dauer 
        END) AS Wert 
FROM Werte 
WHERE Mitarbeiter IN (:mitarbeiter);
```

It would be simpler to write as:

```
       (CASE WHEN Storno = 1 THEN - Dauer
             WHEN Storno = 0 THEN Dauer 
        END) AS Wert
```

Or if `Storno` only takes on the values of 0 and 1:

```
(1 - 2 * Storno) * Dauer as Wert
```

I doubt that `* -1` is your problem, unless there is an unusual character in the string.

The index 1 out of range error is due to *java*, not *SQL*.  It is indicating an error in the query where it could not run.  **You should be checking the error coming back from the database to see what is happening.**

Comment: Because when im leaving out the -1 the code works fine (no matter that the values are not correct then). Furthermore i am using MapSqlParameterSource for the mitarbeiter param and this class can handle a List<String<> as a parameter.